# Return required for Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

why do we need to add 'return' to the ternary operator on line 4? 
when I evaluate a standalone ternary operator such as `'five' === 'five' ? 1 : 0` I get a return value of 1. So my understanding is that a value was returned with that expression. So the 'return' on line 4 seems unnecessary although it is definitely needed for the code to run.

```
var countOccurrence = function(array, value) {
    var n =array.length - 1;
    if(n===0) {
        return array[0] === value ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        if(array[n] === value) {
            return 1 + countOccurrence(array.slice(0,n), value)
        } else {
            return countOccurrence(array.slice(0,n), value)
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You must return something from the function regardless. You can drop all the elses if you are returning `var countOccurrence = function(array, value) {
    var n =array.length - 1;

    if(n===0) return array[0] === value ? 1 : 0;
    if(array[n] === value) return 1 + countOccurrence(array.slice(0,n), value);
    return countOccurrence(array.slice(0,n), value);
}`

Comment: No, if you don't have a `return` statement in your function every call will yield `undefined`.

Comment: The return is not related to the ternary operator - it's related to your `countOccurrence` function

Comment: "*when I evaluate a standalone ternary operator*" - I assume you did this on the console? Yes, there it shows the result that the expression evaluated to. However, the console is very different from putting expression inside a function body. A function needs an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I was running it on the console...

Answer (score 1):

Unlike input on the devtools console, JavaScript `function`s do not return the result value of the last statement to be evaluated. You need an explicit `return` keyword to terminate the function and return a result to the caller. If the function body evaluation ends without a `return`, the value `undefined` is returned implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answers have stated, you need to explicitly return a result, otherwise the result of a function will be `undefined`. This can be done by using the `return` keyword, but since javascript ES6, the `return` keyword is no longer neccessary when using an arrow function expression.

The following function:

```
const fn = function(x, y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

could be written in ES6 in the following way (without the need for the `return` keyword):

```
const fn = (x, y) => x+y;
```

With this in mind (and some functional programming principles), we could rewrite your function `countOccurrence` in the following way:

```js
const countOccurrence = array => value => array.filter(y => y == value).length;
        
const array = [2,3,2,4,2];
const valueToCheck = 2;
console.log(countOccurrence(array)(valueToCheck)); // => 3
```